# Mechanize for bing and yahoo search engine

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, screen-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

How can we implement Mechanize for bing and yahoo search engine? For google implementation seems to be far simple

```
@agent = Mechanize.new
page = @agent.get('http://www.google.com')
google_form = page.form_with(:name => 'f')
google_form.q = query
page = @agent.submit(google_form)
```

but I am not sure how to implement this for other two search engines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yahoo:

```
@agent.get('http://www.yahoo.com/').forms[0].tap{|f| f.p = 'foo'}.submit
```

Bing:

```
@agent.get('http://www.bing.com/').forms[0].tap{|f| f.q = 'foo'}.submit
```